# How to call another function in a different class from SerialPort Eventhandler, process the data and update the form?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, class, serial-port

I have two different classes, one which i have my form on (Form1), and one where i have SerialPort communication on (SerialPortCom). I can send and get data from the serialport, but when i send the data to form1, and try to put it in a textbox, the textbox never updates.

How do i from SerialPortCom´s SerialPort Eventhandler call a function in Form1, where i can update the form and process the data?

My SerialPort code is heavely inspired by PsychoCoder Serial Port Communication In C# tutorial : https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/#/
He updates the textbox from SerialPort class, but i would like to send the string to Form1, so i can process it before i display it.

I have tried calling TextBox.update, Invalidate, refresh.
I also tried

```
public void data(string message)
{
    messagereceived = message;

    if (modtag_textbox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        modtag_textbox.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate { modtag_textbox.Text = message; }));
    }
    else
    {
        modtag_textbox.Text = message;              
    }
}
```

But it never went into the if statement. And if i put it ouside the if statement, it throws an error.

The code from SerialPortCom eventhandler is:

```
[STAThread]
void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = SerialPort1.ReadExisting();

    Form1 test = new Form1();
    test.data(msg);
}
```

It has no problem going into the eventhandler, and it also call the data() function in Form1.

I want to send the msg from SerialPortCom to a function in Form1, from there process the data, and display it in the forms textbox.

Thanks for the help,
Klaus Hammer

Comment: You create new `Form` on each event.

Comment: Isn´t that what im doing with Form1 test = new Form1();?

Comment: As I understand you already have Form1 created with application start. You create every time new object and pass data to this new form not the existing. So you need for example create `SerialPortCom` in `Form1` and pass reference to `Form1` into `SerialPortCom`. Remove `Form1 test = new Form1();` and use reference to `Form1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your form in the class you have for your serial port, then make a function in your form class that updates the UI.  It can be done on the `Form Load` Event, see my example below:

```
//Your main form
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mySerialClass msc = new mySerialClass(this);
        msc.startSerialLogic(); //start our serial logic
    }

    public updateGUI(string s)
    {
        textbox1.Text = s;
    }
}

//your class with your serial logic
class mySerialClass
{
    private Form1 f1;

    public mySerialClass(Form1 myForm)
    {
        f1 = myForm;
    }

    public void startSerialLogic()
    {
        //start your serial stuff here
    }

    private void updateFormGUI(string s)
    {
        f1.updateGUI(s);
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateFormGUI(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
    }
}
```

So whenever you want to update your UI from your class with the serial logic, you can just call `updateFormGUI` which will call your function from your main form `f1.updateGUI(s);`.  Obviously it doesn't need to be a string, this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked! :) I had to add a delegate to update the form, but other than that, what you wrote worked.

Comment: Yeah, the `DateReceived` event is on it's own thread, so to update the gui you'll have to invoke it.  Should have mentioned that, but glad you figured it out.